# Twin paradox along a hyperbolic worldline

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

Let Bob stay at Earth, positioned at $x = \alpha c t_0$, with $\alpha > 1$. Alice travels on the worldline $-c^2t^2 + x^2 = c^2t^2_0$. $t_0$ is a positive constant. I am trying to work out how by how much Alice and Bob have aged between Alice leaving, and returning to Bob.

Alice travels on a worldline which takes the form of the hyperbola parameterised by $(ct_0 \cosh(t), t_0\sinh(t))$ (note we are only interested in the x-positive part, since $\alpha > 1$). She is at $x = \alpha ct_0$ when $t = cosh^{-1}(\alpha)$. These correspond to time-axis-coordinates $\pm t_0 \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1}$. So Alice begins at $(ct_0\cosh^{-1}(\alpha), -t_0\sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1})$ and finishes at $(ct_0\cosh^{-1}(\alpha), t_0\sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1})$. The difference in time coordinate is $2t_0 \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1}$. If this is how much she ages, then Bob's age can be worked out by using the Lorentz transformations to relate Alice's frame to his.
However, apparently the answer is $2t_0 \cosh^{-1}(\alpha)$. What went wrong in my calculation of time elapsed in Alice's frame?

In general, can the worldline be parameterised like this in order to work out when events in spacetime occur?

Comment: I confess I don't follow your scenario, but if Alice does not travel in a straight line then you have to calculate her elapsed time by integration along her trajectory.

Comment: I have drawn a diagram but I did not know how to attach images. The diagram is easy to draw though (hyperbola through focus at ct_0, straight line through $\alpha ct_0$) @SamGinrich

Answer (score 1):

We can parameterise the worldline by
$$ ct(\lambda) = ct_0 \sinh\lambda \qquad x(\lambda) = ct_0\cosh\lambda$$
Alice meets Bob when she returns to the coordinate $x=\alpha ct_0$ in Bob's frame. This happens at $\lambda = \pm \cosh^{-1} (\alpha)$ or when $t = \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1}$. Thus Bob ages by $2t_0\sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1}$.

It is a bit trickier to calculate how much Alice has aged. She is accelerating, so we have to integrate over the space-time trajectory.
\begin{align*}
\tau &= \int_{-\cosh^{-1} (\alpha)}^{\cosh^{-1} (\alpha)} \frac{1}{c}\sqrt{c^2 \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2}  \mathrm{d}\lambda \\
&= \int_{-\cosh^{-1} (\alpha)}^{\cosh^{-1} (\alpha)} \frac{1}{c} \cdot c t_0   \mathrm{d}\lambda \\
&= 2 t_0 \cosh^{-1} (\alpha)
\end{align*}
as desired.

Note that the calculations you have done are in Bob's frame so it is how much Bob ages and not Alice. The reason we have to integrate to find out how much Alice has aged is because Alice is accelerating.